# How to log Windows Advanced Firewall rule matches?

Tags: windows, windows-firewall

One server should accept connection to certain a port from only one IP. However it accepts this connection from any IP even without any explicit rules. While manually disabling-enabling each rule to find the offending one would be an option, it is tedious and might affect operations.

Default Windows Firewall connection logging only shows IF a connection was allowed or dropped. I want to find out WHY it was allowed or dropped (what rules matched the connection).